# how to load basic setting into angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I am new to AngularJS and MVC.

I used to do websites in a "spaghetti" way.

Now I want to load some basic settings into my website, but not via AJAX after the DOM is loaded.

For example, Google Analytics Account ID could be defined by client at the backend system.

It should be loaded together with the page, but not by AJAX.

As my main page is index.htm, loading every data by javascript.

Without being "spaghetti" way, what is the best practice I should follow to?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If your back end outputs those settings into an object on window, like..

```
window.appSettings = {
   setting1: 'abc'
};
```

In angular, you can make it injectable by putting it in an constant like:

```
angular.module('YourModule').constant('appSettings', window.appSettings);
```

Then in your services, controllers, and directives, you can use those settings:

```
angular.module('YourModule').controller('SomeController', ['appSettings', function(appSettings) {
   //use appSettings.setting1
}]);
```

Comment: how should I output this file?
window.appSettings = {setting1: 'abc';} I can think of PHP writing into a JS, since I need these settings from database.

Comment: That's exactly how you would do it. Instead of 'abc', just use php to output your value. Setting those would just be in a script tag in your main php file.